# Extend axis limits without plotting (in order to align two plots by x-unit)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to combine two ggplot objects with `patchwork` - two plots with different subsets of data, but the same x variable (and therefore same unit). I would like to align the plots according to the x values - **Each x unit should have the same physical width in the final plot**.

This is very easy when actually plotting the entire width of the larger data set (see plot below) - but I struggle to plot only parts of the data and keeping the same alignment.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(patchwork)
library(dplyr)

p1 <- 
ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg)) + 
  geom_density(trim = TRUE) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(10,35))

p2 <- 
ggplot(filter(mtcars, mpg < 20), aes(mpg)) + 
  geom_histogram(binwidth = 1, boundary = 1) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(10,35)) 

p1/p2
```

[image]
<sup>Created on 2019-08-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

**The desired output**
 <sup>That's photoshopped</sup>

[image]
adding `coord_cartesian(xlim = c(10,(20 or 35)), clip = 'off')`, and/or changing `scale_x` limits to `c(0,(20 or 35))` doesn't work.

`patchwork` also won't let me set the widths of both plots when they are in two rows, which makes sense in a way. So I could create an empty plot for the second row and set the widths for those, but this seems a terrible hack and I feel there must be a much easier solution.
I am not restricted to `patchwork`, but any solution allowing to use it would be very welcome.

Comment: Given you mention *terrible hack*, add `breaks = c(10, 15, 20)` to the `scale_x_continuous` call and then `p2 = p2 + geom_rect(aes(xmin=20, xmax=Inf, ymin=-Inf, ymax=Inf),    fill="white")` gets you most of the way there.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I modified the `align_plots` function from the cowplot package for this, so that its `plot_grid` function can now support adjustments to the dimensions of each plot.

(The main reason I went with cowplot rather than patchwork is that I haven't had much tinkering experience with the latter, and overloading common operators like `+` makes me slightly nervous.)

**Demonstration of results**

```
# x / y axis range of p1 / p2 have been changed for illustration purpose
p1 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, 1 + stat(count))) + 
  geom_density(trim = TRUE) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(10,35)) +
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(1, 3.5))

p2 <- ggplot(filter(mtcars, mpg >= 15 & mpg < 30), aes(mpg)) + 
  geom_histogram(binwidth = 1, boundary = 1) 

plot_grid(p1, p2, ncol = 1, align = "v") # plots in 1 column, x-axes aligned
plot_grid(p1, p2, nrow = 1, align = "h") # plots in 1 row, y-axes aligned
```

Plots in 1 column (x-axes aligned for 15-28 range):

[image: x-axes aligned]

Plots in 1 row (y-axes aligned for 1 - 3.5 range):

[image: y-axes aligned]

**Caveats**

1. This hack assumes the plots that the user intends to align (either horizontally or vertically) have **reasonably similar axes of comparable magnitude**. I haven't tested it on more extreme cases.
2. This hack expects **simple non-faceted plots in Cartesian coordinates**. I'm not sure what one could expect from aligning faceted plots. Similarly, I'm not considering polar coordinates (what's there to align?) or map projections (haven't looked into this, but they feel rather complicated).
3. This hack expects the gtable cell containing the plot panel to be in the **7th row / 5th column** of the gtable object, which is based on my understanding of how ggplot objects are typically converted to gtables, and may not survive changes to the underlying code.

**Code**

Modified version of `cowplot::align_plots`:

```
align_plots_modified <- function (..., plotlist = NULL, align = c("none", "h", "v", "hv"),
                                  axis = c("none", "l", "r", "t", "b", "lr", "tb", "tblr"), 
                                  greedy = TRUE) {
  plots <- c(list(...), plotlist)
  num_plots <- length(plots)
  grobs <- lapply(plots, function(x) {
    if (!is.null(x)) as_gtable(x)
    else NULL
  })
  halign <- switch(align[1], h = TRUE, vh = TRUE, hv = TRUE, FALSE)
  valign <- switch(align[1], v = TRUE, vh = TRUE, hv = TRUE, FALSE)
  vcomplex_align <- hcomplex_align <- FALSE
  if (valign) {

    # modification: get x-axis value range associated with each plot, create union of
    # value ranges across all plots, & calculate the proportional width of each plot
    # (with white space on either side) required in order for the plots to align
    plot.x.range <- lapply(plots, function(x) ggplot_build(x)$layout$panel_params[[1]]$x.range)
    full.range <- range(plot.x.range)
    plot.x.range <- lapply(plot.x.range,
                           function(x) c(diff(c(full.range[1], x[1]))/ diff(full.range),
                                         diff(x)/ diff(full.range),
                                         diff(c(x[2], full.range[2]))/ diff(full.range)))

    num_widths <- unique(lapply(grobs, function(x) {
      length(x$widths)
    }))
    num_widths[num_widths == 0] <- NULL
    if (length(num_widths) > 1 || length(grep("l|r", axis[1])) > 0) {
      vcomplex_align = TRUE
      warning("Method not implemented for faceted plots. Placing unaligned.")
      valign <- FALSE
    }
    else {
      max_widths <- list(do.call(grid::unit.pmax, 
                                 lapply(grobs, function(x) {x$widths})))
    }
  }
  if (halign) {

    # modification: get y-axis value range associated with each plot, create union of
    # value ranges across all plots, & calculate the proportional width of each plot
    # (with white space on either side) required in order for the plots to align
    plot.y.range <- lapply(plots, function(x) ggplot_build(x)$layout$panel_params[[1]]$y.range)
    full.range <- range(plot.y.range)
    plot.y.range <- lapply(plot.y.range,
                           function(x) c(diff(c(full.range[1], x[1]))/ diff(full.range),
                                         diff(x)/ diff(full.range),
                                         diff(c(x[2], full.range[2]))/ diff(full.range)))

    num_heights <- unique(lapply(grobs, function(x) {
      length(x$heights)
    }))
    num_heights[num_heights == 0] <- NULL
    if (length(num_heights) > 1 || length(grep("t|b", axis[1])) > 0) {
      hcomplex_align = TRUE
      warning("Method not implemented for faceted plots. Placing unaligned.")
      halign <- FALSE
    }
    else {
      max_heights <- list(do.call(grid::unit.pmax, 
                                  lapply(grobs, function(x) {x$heights})))
    }
  }
  for (i in 1:num_plots) {
    if (!is.null(grobs[[i]])) {
      if (valign) {
        grobs[[i]]$widths <- max_widths[[1]]

        # modification: change panel cell's width to a proportion of unit(1, "null"),
        # then add whitespace to the left / right of the plot's existing gtable
        grobs[[i]]$widths[[5]] <- unit(plot.x.range[[i]][2], "null")
        grobs[[i]] <- gtable::gtable_add_cols(grobs[[i]], 
                                              widths = unit(plot.x.range[[i]][1], "null"), 
                                              pos = 0)
        grobs[[i]] <- gtable::gtable_add_cols(grobs[[i]], 
                                              widths = unit(plot.x.range[[i]][3], "null"), 
                                              pos = -1)
      }
      if (halign) {
        grobs[[i]]$heights <- max_heights[[1]]

        # modification: change panel cell's height to a proportion of unit(1, "null"),
        # then add whitespace to the bottom / top of the plot's existing gtable
        grobs[[i]]$heights[[7]] <- unit(plot.y.range[[i]][2], "null")
        grobs[[i]] <- gtable::gtable_add_rows(grobs[[i]], 
                                              heights = unit(plot.y.range[[i]][1], "null"), 
                                              pos = -1)
        grobs[[i]] <- gtable::gtable_add_rows(grobs[[i]], 
                                              heights = unit(plot.y.range[[i]][3], "null"), 
                                              pos = 0)
      }
    }
  }
  grobs
}
```

Utilising the above modified function with cowplot package's `plot_grid`:

```
# To start using (in current R session only; effect will not carry over to subsequent session)
trace(cowplot::plot_grid, edit = TRUE)
# In the pop-up window, change `grobs <- align_plots(...)` (at around line 27) to
# `grobs <- align_plots_modified(...)`

# To stop using
untrace(cowplot::plot_grid)
```

(Alternatively, we can define a modified version of `plot_grid` function that uses `align_plots_modified` instead of `cowplot::align_plots`. Results would be the same either way.)

Comment: Great answer. Would love to see this become a part of `cowplot`. Please consider submitting a pull request. Thanks

Comment: @Tung see here: https://github.com/wilkelab/cowplot/issues/173 - The package maintainer says this is interesting, but it would probably require substantial work, which was expected.

Comment: FYI, I opened a PR with this solution, so maybe a future version of cowplot is able to do it: https://github.com/wilkelab/cowplot/pull/192

Answer (score 6):

Here is an option with `grid.arrange` that does not use a blank plot, but requires a manual of adjustment of:

- plot margin
- x axis expansion
- number of decimal places in y axis labels

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(gridExtra)

p1 <- 
  ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg)) + 
  geom_density(trim = TRUE) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(10,35), breaks=seq(10,35,5), expand = expand_scale(add=c(0,0))) 

p2 <- 
  ggplot(filter(mtcars, mpg < 20), aes(mpg)) + 
  geom_histogram(binwidth = 1, boundary = 1) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(10,20), breaks=seq(10,20,5), expand = expand_scale(add=c(0,0))) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::number_format(accuracy = 0.01)) +
  theme(plot.margin = unit(c(0,1,0,0), "cm"))

grid.arrange(p1, p2,
  layout_matrix = rbind(c(1, 1), c(2, NA))
)
```

Should make this plot:

[image]