# Consistent y-axis for insetting plots with different heights

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to inset several plots on the same graph with different heights but have the same y scales. In the example below I have two plots with different heights. When I plot them the y-axis don't correspond to one another. How can I programmatically 'align' these two graphs?

Thanks

```
library(dplyr)
library(gridExtra)

plot_1 = data.frame(x = 1:250,
                    y = 1:250) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = x, y = y)) +geom_point()+ scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,250), expand = c(0, 0)) +
  theme(legend.position="none",axis.title.x=element_blank(),axis.text.x=element_blank(),axis.ticks.x=element_blank()) 
plot_2 = data.frame(x = 1:250,
                    y = 1:250*3) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = x, y = y)) +geom_point()+ scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,750), expand = c(0, 0)) + 
  theme(legend.position="none",axis.title.x=element_blank(),axis.text.x=element_blank(),axis.ticks.x=element_blank()) 

base <- ggplot(data.frame(x = 1:1000,
                          y = 1:1000), aes(x, y)) +
  geom_blank() +
  theme_bw()

base = base + 
  annotation_custom(grob = ggplotGrob(plot_1),
                    ymin = 0,
                    ymax = 250,
                    xmin = 0,
                    xmax = 200) 

base = base + 
  annotation_custom(grob = ggplotGrob(plot_2),
                    ymin = 0,
                    ymax = 750,
                    xmin = 300,
                    xmax = 500) 


base
```

Note that the graph below shows the y-axis aren't on the same scale.

[image: output]

Comment: OP, it's a bit unclear what you are looking to have as the desired output.  `plot_2` has y values that range up to 750, whereas `plot_1` goes up to 250.  Are you looking to align the scales *of the insets* with the scale of the main plot?

Comment: @chemdork123 Yes - I'd like the y-axis to align based on the numeric value. For example; the first max height doesn't go to250 for the original main plot but is slightly below.

Comment: very related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57392541/extend-axis-limits-without-plotting-in-order-to-align-two-plots-by-x-unit

Answer (score 2):

OP notes the y axes are not on the same scale in the inset plot - presumably, they mean compared to the original plot.  The reasoning behind this is that the plot itself is not defined only by the size of the area used for plotting, but also includes all the border elements around the plot + a margin.  The inset plots have no x axis labels, so to have the y axes align, all that is needed is to remove the margin around the plot which is added by default:

```
base <-
  ggplot(data.frame(x = 1:1000, y = 1:1000), aes(x, y)) +
  geom_blank() +
  theme_bw() +
  annotation_custom(
    grob = ggplotGrob(plot_1 + theme(plot.margin = margin())),
      ymin = 0, ymax = 250,
      xmin = 0, xmax = 200) +
  annotation_custom(
    grob = ggplotGrob(plot_2 + theme(plot.margin = margin())),
      ymin = 0, ymax = 750,
      xmin = 300, xmax = 500) 
base
```

[image]

If you notice... it's not *perfect*.  There's a bit of space below each inset plot, so the 0 values do not align completely.  What's going on here?  Well, even though OP applied `theme(axis.ticks.x = element_blank())`, "blanking" basically means "drawing them as nothing".  The ticks are *actually still there*, just not drawn.  This means, the total plot area *includes the size of the ticks*.  To remove this little space below the plot, we have to set the size of the axis ticks to zero:

```
base <-
  ggplot(data.frame(x = 1:1000, y = 1:1000), aes(x, y)) +
  geom_blank() +
  theme_bw() +
  annotation_custom(
    grob = ggplotGrob(plot_1 + theme(plot.margin = margin(), axis.ticks.length.x = unit(0,'pt'))),
      ymin = 0, ymax = 250,
      xmin = 0, xmax = 200) +
  annotation_custom(
    grob = ggplotGrob(plot_2 + theme(plot.margin = margin(), axis.ticks.length.x = unit(0,'pt'))),
      ymin = 0, ymax = 750,
      xmin = 300, xmax = 500) 
base
```

[image]

That fixes it.

Comment: this is it! Thankyou!

For future reference do you know how to extract the heights of margins so I can compensate graphs with labels in the future? @chemdork123

Comment: Not perfect - so I made an edit.  It seems `axis.ticks.length.x` must also be set to 0 or the ticks are "drawn" as blanks and the size of the overall plot in the inset extends too far down.

Comment: Compensating for margins created with labels is... tricky.  There might be a gtable way of doing that, which can extract all the elements from the plot drawn via `grid`.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't perfect but might work with some tweaking.

```
base <- ggplot(data.frame(x = 1:1000,
                          y = 1:1000), aes(x, y)) +
  geom_blank() +
  theme_bw()

y_scaling <- 0.8
y_border <- 50
y_max <- function(plot) {
  (diff(range(plot$data$y)) + y_border) * y_scaling
}
y_max(plot_1)


base = base + 
  annotation_custom(grob = ggplotGrob(plot_1),
                    ymin = 0,
                    ymax = y_max(plot_1),
                    xmin = 0,
                    xmax = 200) 

base = base + 
  annotation_custom(grob = ggplotGrob(plot_2),
                    ymin = 0,
                    ymax = y_max(plot_2),
                    xmin = 300,
                    xmax = 500) 


base
```

[image]