# ggplot2: Can I fix the absolute distance between two values on an axis?

Tags: r, ggplot2

My problem seems quite basic, but I couldn't find any relevant answer. I want to create line plots with the date on the x axis. The y axis will be Covid statistics (deaths, hospitalizations, you name it). I want to create a separate plot for the different waves of the pandemic which means that my charts cover different times. My problem is that R fixes the plot to the same size and thus the lines for the shorter time period are skewed in comparison to those of the longer time period. Ideally, I would want 1 month on the x axis to be fixed to a certain number of px or mm. But I can't find out how. My best idea so far is to assign both plots a different total width, but that doesn't give me an optimal result either.
Here's a reproducible example with a built-in dataset to explain:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
economics_1967 <- economics %>%
  filter(date<"1968-01-01")
economics_1968 <- economics %>%
  filter(date<"1969-01-01"&date>"1967-12-31")
#data is only available for six months in 1967, but for 12 in 1968
exampleplot1 <- ggplot(economics_1967)+
  geom_line(aes(date, unemploy))+
  scale_x_date(date_breaks="1 month", date_labels="%b")
#possible: ggsave("exampleplot1.png", width=2, height=1)

exampleplot2 <- ggplot(economics_1968)+
  geom_line(aes(date, unemploy))+
  scale_x_date(date_breaks="1 month", date_labels="%b")
ggsave("exampleplot2.png", width=4, height=1)
#possible: ggsave("exampleplot1.png", width=2, height=1)
```

Thank you!

EDIT: Thanks for the suggestions! Facet wrap would be a good idea but in the end I decided to just plot the whole time in one case. The background is that I classified countries differently for their policies in different times, so that's why I wanted to have a clear break in the visualization, but I just put a vertical line in there.

Comment: This is a tricky one. You can scale the width of the saved graph based on some calculated max value of the `x` axis for example. However, this doesn't account for the space around the plot. You can ensure changes in your legend don't alter the fraction of the total plot size occupied by the plot by setting wide margins. But all of this is a bit of a hack.

Comment: Here's a somewhat related question that looks at approaches to make multiple ggplots have the same y scaling, might be adaptable here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/70945828/6851825

Answer (score 3):

`facet_grid` is one approach, if you don't mind showing the two charts together.

```
library(dplyr); library(ggplot2)
bind_rows(e1967 = economics_1967,
          e1968 = economics_1968, .id="source") %>%
  ggplot(aes(date, unemploy)) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_x_date(date_breaks="1 month", date_labels="%b") +
  facet_grid(~source, scales = "free_x", space = "free_x")
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I like @Jon Spring's solution a lot.  I want to present it a tad differently --to show that `facet()` usually operates on a single dataset that has one existing variable used to facet.

```r
econ_subset <- 
  economics %>%
  dplyr::filter(dplyr::between(date, as.Date("1967-09-01"), as.Date("1968-12-31"))) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(
    year = lubridate::year(date) # Used below to facet
  )

ggplot(econ_subset, aes(date, unemploy)) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_x_date(date_breaks="1 month", date_labels="%b") +
  facet_grid(~year, scales = "free_x", space = "free_x")
```

[image]

(In Jon's solution, `bind_rows()` is used to stack the two separate datasets back together.)